# How to tell the compiler to unroll this loop

Tags: c, gcc, arm, loop-unrolling

I have the following loop that I am running on an ARM processor.

```
// pin here is pointer to some part of an array
for (i = 0; i < v->numelements; i++)
{
    pe   = pptr[i];
    peParent = pe->parent;

    SPHERE  *ps = (SPHERE *)(pe->data);

    pin[0] = FLOAT2FIX(ps->rad2);
    pin[1] = *peParent->procs->pe_intersect == &SphPeIntersect;
    fixifyVector( &pin[2], ps->center ); // Is an inline function

    pin = pin + 5;
}
```

By the slow performance of the loop, I can judge that the compiler was unable to unroll this loop, as when I manually do the unrolling, it becomes quite fast. I think the compiler is getting confused by the `pin` pointer. Can we use `restrict` keyword to help the compiler here, or is `restrict` only reserved for function parameters? In general how can we tell the compiler to unroll it and don't worry about the `pin` pointer.

Comment: Did you measure execution times on a debug or release build?

Comment: Release build with -O3 optimization.

Comment: have you tried to assign `v->numelements` to a local and using that in the for loop? Could be the compiler cannot unroll the loop because it has to assume the value of `v->numelements` will be changed in `fixifyVector`.

Comment: fixifyVector is inlined, so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: gcc also has -funroll-loops optimization flag looking at the [docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) it has to be enabled separately from -O3

Comment: I don't see anything in that code that would be helped significantly by unrolling the loop.  You're going to have to look at the generated object code for the two cases to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @RobertPrior You should post it as an answer since I bet that's it. I don't think any compiler will do (heavy) loop unrolling unasked for, since it is quite ineffective in terms of program memory space.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm Doesn't that depend on `numelements`? If it is in millions, you can avoid many code jumps and thus comparisons by unrolling. Or are there other benefits to loop unrolling that cannot be gained in this segment?

Comment: You might want to add the specific ARM CPU, it is probably important to a performance related question.

Comment: @jsn, what I see is an array lookup, several pointer manipulations, and a function invocation.  My gut feel is that these will completely dominate the per-iteration time, compared to the loop overhead.  The guy could make a significant improvement by caching v->numelements in the loop initialization, instead of fetching it every time through, but that shouldn't be that expensive an operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To tell gcc to unroll all loops you can use the optimization flag `-funroll-loops`.

To unroll only a specific loop you can use:

```
__attribute__((optimize("unroll-loops")))
```

see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14251545/2040707) for more details.

**Edit**

If the compiler cannot determine the number of iterations of the loop upon entry you will need to use `-funroll-all-loops`. Note that from the [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.4/gcc/Optimize-Options.html): `"Unroll all loops, even if their number of iterations is uncertain when the loop is entered. This usually makes programs run more slowly."`

Answer (score 0):

If you extent `pptr` size by one, you can use the `pld` instruction.

```
  __asm__ __volatile__("pld\t[%0]" :: "r" (pptr[i+1]));
```

Or alternatively you may need to pre-load the **next** `peParent` and `SPHERE  *ps`.  The loop overhead on an ARM is very small.  It is unlikely that un-rolling the loop will be a significant benefit. There are no loop variable constants.  It is more likely that the compiler's scheduler is able to fetch advanced data before it is used when you have un-rolled the loop.

You have not presented all of the code to see the data dependencies.  There maybe other variables that would benefit from being *pre-loaded*.  Giving a complete example would probably help everyone answer your question.

Comment: This answer is more likely on Cortex type CPU's where the pipeline is larger.  The specific ARM CPU wasn't mentioned.